# module 'cython' has no attribute 'annotation_typing'

Tags: python-3.x, cython

I just recently updated Cython from 0.29.24 to 3.0.0a11 and I was getting compilation errors due to functions that were using Dict type hints.  With the previous versions, I never had any issues of this type (no pun intended). I compile my entire python project by building Extensions using cythonize in a setup.py file.  I am using Python 3.9.13.

After doing some reading I attempted to solve the issues I was having by using the [compiler directive](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html#disabling-annotations) as follows:

```
import cython

@cython.annotation_typing(False)
def my_function_with_type_hints(this_object: Dict) -> Dict:
   pass
```

Compilation succeeded although I have not tested my compiled code yet.  I returned to development to test some new code and now I am unable to run code in interpeter mode because Cython is complaining "module 'cython' has no attribute 'annotation_typing'".  I confirmed (via pip freeze) that Cython==3.0.0a11 is installed in my environment and that my environment is activated (in vscode).

My questions:

1. Did I fix the typing issue correctly using the compiler directive or am I not understanding the problem fully?
2. How should I be using compiler directives in interpreter mode? Do I need another decorator that conditionally includes the cython directive?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I think it's a bug and you should report it on the Cython bug tracker. You can probably monkey-patch it into the `cython` module when in interpreted mode, but you shouldn't have to.

Comment: I.e. what you're doing is right and *should* work correctly

Comment: Thank you @DavidW, I will contact the Cython team via their bug tracker.

Comment: I suspect your short term workaround looks something like `if not cython.compiled: cython.annotation_typing = cython.boundscheck` (but not able to test it right now)

Comment: Thank you again, I will investigate this method and also try conditional decorators using `cython.compiled`.

Comment: Legitimate [bug](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/5194) with Cython, thanks again @DavidW!